# Trying to make an application that can communicate with other phones nearby

Tags: audio, mobile, bluetooth, gps, wifi

I have been tirelessly trying to decide on the best option for getting phones to talk to each other that are nearby, I need something with the ability to broadcast and receive.  It is kind of like NFC with more range, I'd like to be able to send messages 30 to 50 feet away using nothing but a phone.

Bluetooth cannot broadcast and receive to more than 8 devices still, there might be changes to that in Apple's new OS but Android and Windows are still going to be lacking, so Bluetooth is out of the question.

I was thinking of maybe trying to use Wifi, but I have not found very many good resources on how I would go about doing that without making a virtual server, I'd much rather not go that route if possible.

I could even use GPS although with the power consumption of GPS and having to be an always on feature I am not certain I would like to use GPS if I can avoid it.

The one I really want to use, uses sounds made and received by the phone.  I have been playing around with a listener that converts different frequencies to 1's and 0's, but with all things sound, it gets increasingly hard if lots of people are talking, or there is music playing, or if there are objects in the way, the Doppler effect and more.  Is there someone out there who has already made a filter for this?  Some other problems would be, what is the range sound travels at 20khz through air?  I can also not find much good documentation anywhere for devices whose speakers can make sound above 20khz but it seems most can, the problem then is what microphones can hear sounds above 20khz.

I would really love to use sound as I think it is interesting, and it would make the app work without any internet or phone connection which I think is pretty cool.  This is a side-project I am working on, and really don't want to spend hours down a path that will ultimately fail.

If anyone thinks it's possible to do this with sound over other devices, I'd much rather like to do it that way, I think there is a lot of interesting things you could do with that technology, I just don't know how viable it is over using wifi or bluetooth or even GPS.

Comment: That sounds silly to use sounds. Other people dont like to be disturbed by such an app. Further the area of akkustik modem is 30 years ago. Better go the Wlan approach, combined with GPS. If you configure the location system to allow low accuracy, then GPS is even not enabled. Wlan locationing and cell tower is used.

Comment: It would be out of the hearing range of people, I should've added that.  The beauty of sounds is you don't need connection to use a messenger service.  The sounds I've tested don't bother my dogs, but I have been worried about other people's dogs.  Mostly because dogs don't care about the sounds unless they have been trained at those frequencies.  i have not been able to test that yet obviously.

Comment: Have you tested what the frequency range of the microphones are? Have you a link to the virtual server approach? I expect that the speaker have not enough power to produce a high frequency signal that can be detected in some meters distance, especially if set to normal speaker level. persons and furniture easiyl block the high frequ sounds.

Comment: I have not tested the microphones from any phones yet, I also cannot find much documentation on them anywhere.  I have tested the microphones built into some laptops, and they seem to do ok, again distance is a problem.  I don't know much about sound, it seems like the Doppler effect + Rebound off of objects is making it incredibly hard for me the farther the distance to send messages.

I have not read up on a lot of the virtual server, I just assumed I would have to make someone's phone the virtual server and everyone message through that.  I would much rather have it happen concurrently.

Comment: At ios you have no controll to low level "things". You can read the current connected wlan ssid, but not all wlan ids which the operation system can see. I would first try the locationin services approach. Settig to 1000m acuarcy will usually disable GPS, but enable cell-tower an wlan locationing. especially the wlan locationing gives an indirect hint that the persons are near the same wlan.

Answer (score 0):

At ios you have no controll to low level "things". You can read the current connected wlan ssid, but not all wlan ids which the operation system can see.
I would first try the location services approach. Settig to 1000m acuarcy will usually disable GPS, but enable cell-tower an wlan locationing. 
Especially the wlan locationing gives an indirect hint that the persons are near the same wlan